# Installed Django and ran now it says command not found

Tags: python, django

I am new to python and Django I have installed Python 3.7 and Django on MacOS 10.14 followed online tutorials I created folder on Desktop  called Development and in that i have test, polls folder.
ran python manage.py runserver  open browser 127.0.0.0:8000 it worked.

Then I was trying sample project from Django website it did not work so next day I want to troubleshoot my code. I cd to development folder ran python manage.py runserver  keep saying command not found.

I could not find answers online. My question do i have to create virtualenv every time I want to open existing Django project? how do I open existing project please if you can give me step by step that would be great.

Comment: you need to activate your virtualenv before running `python ...`

Answer (score 2):

You just need to activate the existing virtual env, you don't need to create a new one.

On Linux/Mac OS, you can do:

```
source /path/to/your/virtualenv/bin/activate
```

Or if you used virtualenvwrapper, then simply"

```
workon yourvirtualenvname
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating Virtual Environment every time is not required.

But every time you plan to work on the Django project and run the server make sure you follow below steps :

```
source path/VirtualEnvName/bin/activate
```

**Note : Replace "path/VirtualEnvName" with your absolute path and Virtual Environment Name

after the above command executes, you'll see VirtualEnvName before the prompt
i.e (virtualEnvName)$

CD into the folder where manage.py is present and execute the below command

```
python manage.py runserver
```

to  exit Press "Ctrl+C"

To deactivate the virtual Env. simply use below command

```
deactivate
```

Comment: Thank you deathdater your solution worked.   I gave absolute path and it worked i was able to open Django webpage finish sample project.  How can I put Django in my path so that in the future I don't have to type absolute.

Comment: You need to copy/cut and paste the virtual Env. directory into your default user folder